# Regex to match everything between a string and a caret (^) excluding occurrence of caret (^)

Tags: sql, regex, regex-negation

Here is the data

```
[StupidHtml]: AZaz.-09^abcdabcd^a^a^
```

I need a regex to retrieve data between `[StupidHtml]:` and first occurrence of `^`

Currently I am using

```
(?<=\[StupidHtml\]\:)(.*)(?=\^)
```

But that results in:

```
AZaz.-09^abcdabcd^a^a
```

I need to achieve `Azaz.-09`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
(?<=\[StupidHtml\]\:)(.*?)(?=\^)
```

Answer (score 2):

Make your regex less greedy by using `(.*?)` instead of `(.*)`:

```
\[StupidHtml\]\:(.*?)\^
```

Comment: (?<=\[StupidHtml\]\:)(.*?)(?=\^) Works well. I believe.

Comment: @user2087959: Is there any particular reason why you're using lookaheads and lookbehinds?

Answer (score 0):

`.` will match any character, even `^`. You need to exclude it from your matching class

Give a try to  `(?<=\[StupidHtml\]\:)([^\^]*)(?=\^)`